# Excel VBA hlookup return 400

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have a sheet with score of the current round and a sheet with total scores.
I need to save the final score of the current round to the sheet with all scores.

The first Hlookup works fine, but at the second Hlookup VBA crashes (400).

```vb
Dim TotSht As Worksheet
Dim NowSht As Worksheet
Set TotSht = Worksheets("Total")
Set NowSht = Worksheets("Current")

TotSht.Range("D1").EntireColumn.Insert
TotSht.Range("D1").Value = NowSht.Range("U1") 'Round number

TotSht.Range("D2").Value = WorksheetFunction.HLookup(TotSht.Range("A2"), NowSht.Range("C2:H3"), 2)
TotSht.Range("D3").Value = WorksheetFunction.HLookup(TotSht.Range("A3"), NowSht.Range("C2:H3"), 2)
TotSht.Range("D4").Value = WorksheetFunction.HLookup(TotSht.Range("A4"), NowSht.Range("C2:H3"), 2)
TotSht.Range("D5").Value = WorksheetFunction.HLookup(TotSht.Range("A5"), NowSht.Range("C2:H3"), 2)
TotSht.Range("D6").Value = WorksheetFunction.HLookup(TotSht.Range("A6"), NowSht.Range("C2:H3"), 2)
TotSht.Range("D7").Value = WorksheetFunction.HLookup(TotSht.Range("A7"), NowSht.Range("C2:H3"), 2)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: If I use "on error resume next" Only the 1st and 3rd gets loaded.
In my dataset, the first 3 Hlookups should return some value, and the 4th has no match.

Comment: The first troubleshooting step would be to try the broken `HLookup` function manually, directly on the worksheet?  In a random empty cell, something like `=HLookup(Total!A3, Current!C2:H3, 2)`. Do you get a more specific error on the worksheet?

Comment: With a range C2 to h3 do you think your data goes further? like C2 to H10?

Comment: Also (maybe you know this already) `on error resume next` can sometimes be handy for troubleshooting purposes but should generally be avoided.  Also handy for troubleshooting is to put `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, to ensure variables and properties are properly decraed/handled.

Comment: The normal '=HLookup(Total!A3, Current!C2:H3, 2)' works perfectly fine. The error is solved, although I don't know why. I have not changed the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is resolved.
What I did was close excel and open it again.